# erasing device data

Tags: android

I am working for a small company that deals in the recycle mobile devices, I have been tasked to re-write the device memory 2-3 times so that it could not be
recovered by any 3rd party recovery tool.

After doing some RnD, I think DoD 5220.22-M data sanitization method would be the best choice to sanitize the device memory.

The DoD 5220.22-M data sanitization method is usually implemented in the following way:

Pass 1: Writes a zero and verifies the write
Pass 2: Writes a one and verifies the write
Pass 3: Writes a random character and verifies the write

Since don't have much experience in Android programming, hence I am looking for some assistance to point me in the right direction to achieve this.

Comment: When you say "recycle mobile devices" is this for sale in the future as a Android device or component recycling? See: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5662/is-it-enough-to-only-wipe-a-flash-drive-once

Comment: Thanks for this link, it will definitely help me. How it would be great if you could forward something in Android programming code.

Comment: I wonder how realistic this is especially with "not much experience in Android". The JAVA APIs are of course limited to file read/write access and I don't know what exactly is possible in [NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/). That would be first thing to study. If you want to do it well, there are always [commercial solutions](https://www.blancco.com/products/mobile-device-eraser/).